# get random ID into an empty array

Tags: jquery

heres the fiddle im working on http://jsfiddle.net/d0okie0612/22cTn/

Im wrote a function getNewId() and i want to get it into my empty array [] everytime i click add location link and each one should have a different random ID per form

so name="locations[random_id_goes_here][street]"
right now its name="locations[][street]"

heres the html

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top_form">
        <form>
            Street: <input class="street" name="[][street]" id="form_element" type="text">          <br><br>
            City: <input class="city" name="[][city]" id="form_element" type="text">
            <select>
                <option value=" ">State</option>
                <option value="ca">CA</option>
                <option value="az">AZ</option>
                <option value="de">DE</option>
            </select>
            Zip: <input name="[][zipcode]" type="text"><br /><br />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<br />
<a href="#" id="awsomeButton">+ Add Loction</a>
<br />
<br />
<button id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
```

heres the jquery

```
var tpl = ""
    + "<div id='location_div_<%= id %>'><h1>My Location #<%= id %></h1></div>";

var newId = new Date().getTime();
var template = _.template(tpl);
var compiled = template({id: newId});

var addedForm = "<div id='added_form'>"
    + "<a href='#' class='close_btn'>x</a>"
    + "Street: <input name='locations[][street]' type='text'>"
    + "<br /><br />"
    + "City: <input name='locations[][city]' type='text'>"
    + "<select>"
    + "<option value=' '>State</option>"
    + "</select>"
    + "Zip: <input name='locations[][zipcode]' type='text'>"
    + "</div>"

function getNewId() {
    var newId = new Date().getTime();
    return newId;
}

$('#awsomeButton').on('click', function (e) {
    $(addedForm).hide().appendTo('form').fadeIn('slow');
    $(getNewId()).appendTo();
});

$('.close_btn').live('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('div#added_form:first').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

so basically im just trying to get the numbers in the empty array any help would be appreciated thank you

Am I asking this question weird?

Answer (score 0):

Add the random number to the first form when the HTML loads. This requires `class='zip'` added to the zip input. I assumed you would also want a unique name for each `state` select:

```
addFirstId();

function addFirstId() {
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*100001);
    var firstId=(new Date().getTime())+randomnumber.toString();
    $(".street").attr("name","locations["+firstId+"][street]");
    $("select").attr("name","locations["+firstId+"][state]");
    $(".city").attr("name","locations["+firstId+"][city]");
    $(".zipcode").attr("name","locations["+firstId+"][zipcode]");
    myArray.push(firstId);
}
```

The following adds each new form with a random number:

```
function getNewId() {
    //Random number is date in milliseconds + another random number added
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*100001);
    var newId=(new Date().getTime())+randomnumber.toString();
    var customForm = addedForm.replace(/\[\]/g,"["+newId+"]");
    myArray.push(newId);
    return customForm;
}

$('#awsomeButton').on('click', function(e) {
    $(getNewId()).hide().appendTo('form').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/Lhqg8/2/).

**Edit**

Added `myArray.push(firstId);` in 2 places above.

Comment: is that the only way to get the my getNewID number into the []?  I'm really new to jQuery and a lot of the code above is going way over my head.  I thought it would be more simple

Comment: The `addFirstId` part above is only required if you want to uniquely identify the first set of form fields the user sees when the pages load. You don't need `randomnumber` either if a random number based just on the current date in milliseconds is sufficient.

Comment: is there a way to just add the getNewId function into my on click event handler? and have it be put into the []

Comment: `getNewId()` *is* in your on click handler above? If you want all the different input elements with `name='location[][blah]'` to have a random number in the `[]`, I believe this is the most straightforward way of doing it. Edited to add each random number to `myArray` also.